# SLURM - Print all output to single out file

Tags: slurm

I want the output of all the jobs to be printed to the same output file `"o.out"`, without overwriting it.

In particular, I want this to work with job arrays:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --array=1-3
#SBATCH -J vo_job
#SBATCH -o o.out
#SBATCH -e e.out
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `--open-mode` option of sbatch:

```
#SBATCH --open-mode=append
```

From the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html):

> Open the output and error files using append or truncate mode as
>   specified. The default value is specified by the system configuration
>   parameter JobFileAppend.

The default is `truncate`, which indeeds erases the previous contents in the file.